# returning duplicate users SQL

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql

so i am using POSTGRES SQL, PGADMIN 3 and NODE.JS to write my sql queries. In my node.js my code looks like this:-

```
var express = require('express'),
cors = require('cors'),
massive = require('massive'),
bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = module.exports = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

//MASSIVE//
var massiveUrl = 'postgres://localhost/cart';
var massiveServer = massive.connectSync({
connectionString: massiveUrl
});

app.set('db', massiveServer);
var db = app.get('db');

//ENDPOINTS//
app.post('/api/user', function(req, res, next) {
db.user_create([req.body.name,req.body.email],function(err, user) {
console.log('user is this: ', user);
if(err) {
  res.status(500).send(err);
}
console.log(user[0].userid);
db.order_create([user[0].userid], function(err, order) {
  console.log('order is this: ', order);
  if(err) {
    return res.status(500).send(err)
  }
  res.status(200).send('User and Order created successfully');
})
})
});

app.get('/api/user', function(req, res, next) {
db.users(function(err, users) {
if(err) {
  res.status(500).send(err);
}
res.status(200).send(users);
})
});


app.listen(3333, function() {
console.log("Listening on port 3333");
});
```

my user_create.sql, order_create.sql and users.sql files look like these:-

```
users.sql:-
SELECT *
FROM users

user_create.sql:-
INSERT INTO users (name, email)
VALUES ($1, $2)
RETURNING *;

order_create.sql
INSERT INTO orders (user_id)
VALUES ($1);
```

The problem is that when I post on postman using POST and the url '/api/user giving it a name and email {"name":"Sam","email":"Sam@gmail.com"} it generates an order_id table with the given user_id. So my users table would have something like userid: 1 name: Sam, email: Sam@gmail.com. Now the userid is set as a SERIAL PRIMARY KEY. The idea is that one user would have many orders. so when i post that same information again using {"name":"Sam","email":"Sam@gmail.com"} i get a new userid: 2 name: Sam email: Sam@gmail.com. clearly this is wrong. It should not give me another userid since its the same user!

```
Table structure:-
create table users
(
 userid SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
 name VARCHAR(40),
 email VARCHAR(255)
)

create table orders
(
 id INTEGER,
 user_id INTEGER references users(userid),
 amounttotal float
)
```

How can i prevent from creating an order and not getting Sam twice with different user ids?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For thing like this I use a stored procedure. In this case I get AVL data from gps devices so I can track where the car is moving. So only need create the car once.

So for your case instead of cars are users.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION avl.car_check(i_car_external_id integer)
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    int_newcar_id bigint;   
BEGIN
    -- CHECK IF CAR ALREADY EXIST AND TRY TO GET ID
    SELECT INTO int_newcar_id
        car_id  -- INTERNAL SERIAL FIELD
    FROM 
        avl.cars_pool
    WHERE 
        car_external_id = i_car_external_id;

    IF int_newcar_id IS null THEN
        -- CREATE A NEW CAR
        INSERT INTO avl.cars_pool
            (car_external_id)
        VALUES
            (i_car_external_id); 

        -- GET THE NEWLY CREATED ID
        SELECT INTO int_newcar_id
            car_id
        FROM 
            avl.cars_pool
        WHERE 
            car_external_id = i_car_external_id;
    END IF;

    RETURN int_newcar_id;
END;
$BODY$
```